# Windshield weather stripping resecure

Tags: toyota, camry, windshield

The weather stripping on my front windshield has detached along the roof. How can I resecure this?

I have called around and no one will do this repair. They do full windshield replacement instead.

2003 Toyota Camry LE

Comment: Did you ask for the reason why they do only full windshield replacement? It may be the case that the operation requires removing the windshield, in which case it might make sense to put some $$$ on the table for a new windshield.

Comment: My Mother-In-Law has an '05 with a lot of weather stripping issues on it, but mainly around the doors (at the base of the windows). She wants me to repair them, but I can tell it'd be a nightmare. Shops want a butt-ton of money to do it ... i can tell why. Wish Toyota would have produced better products on these.

Answer (score 3):

In order to repair/replace the weather stripping around the windshield, you have to remove the windshield. I don't know if you know the process for removing them, but let's just say the success rate is very low with out breakage. I used to work in a junk yard. If a customer wanted us to pull the glass out of an old car, they'd have to pay for it up front, regardless if we pulled it successfully. If we broke it, they got nothing. I'd say the success rate for removal is probably under 25%, and that's with two someones who know what they are doing.

Comment: Used to have to remove the screens on cars to fit roof aerials - heavy rubber seals and 100% success rate - then they started to use the sealer to glue in screens, luckily by then aerials came as standard. But we removed those using a cheese wire - again no choice as we would be on the end of a serious serious bo**ocking from the service manager...

Comment: @SolarMike - When the windshields had the rubber seals with the rubber cord to set them in place, it was a lot easier to remove/install with success ... absolutely agree with you. Now that they are glued? It's a tough job. My hat's off to anyone who does it successfully, that's for sure.

Comment: luckily it was much rarer to have to remove the later ones... Usually due to a wiring loom fire and having to replace the headlining.